# How to show an text editing box "over" the screen?

Tags: android, text, popup, android-edittext

I have an application that has a primary layout of portrait (it is fixed as portrait), and there is one place to type in text. I would like to launch like a popup window in landscape orientation with the background image fogged out. I know there is a Popup Widget, but any ideas for rotating the text edit box would be great. Rotating it into a portrait view (text box only) when the keyboard is slid out would also work, as would showing a new screen with the text box on keyboard slide.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The easiest solution to your problem is to display your `EditText` within a separate `dialog` themed Activity that you launch from within your main (portrait-fixed) Activity.

The EditText Activity shouldn't have its orientation fixed, so it will rotate as you'd expect when you slide out the keyboard.

**Creating the Text Entry Activity**

Create a new Activity the contains only the EditText View and anything else you want to include (probably OK / Cancel buttons and maybe a label?). Within the manifest set its theme to `Theme.Dialog`.

```
<activity android:name="TextEntryActivity" 
          android:label="My Activity" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

Fogging or Blurring the Activities behind a dialog is done by modifying the Window properties of the foreground Activity (your text entry dialog). Within it's onCreate method use `getWindow().setFlags` to apply blurring to any background Activities.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,  
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

**Launching and Reading Entered Values from the Text Entry Activity**

Use `startActivityForResult` to launch the text entry Activity. Within that Activity call `setResult` to return the text string entered within the returned intent using the techniques described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449484/android-capturing-the-return-of-an-activity#449824).

Override the `onActivityResult` method to listen for the result from the sub Activity.

**Triggering Launch on Keyboard Exposed**

You can launch the text entry Activity whenever you want, but if you want to always display it when the keyboard is exposed you can capture this event explicitely.

Start by adding the `android:configChanges` attribute to the portrait Activity's manifest entry. It should be registered to listen for `keyboardHidden`.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

Within that Activity, override `onConfigurationChanged` to launch the text entry Activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {  
  Intent i = new Intent(this,TextEntryActivity.class);    
  startActivityForResult(i, STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE);
}
```

You may want to check to confirm the keyboard is being exposed (rather than hidden) using the newConfig variable before launching the text entry Activity.

You may also want to use the same technique to automatically return from the text entry activity when the keyboard is hidden.