# How to set a dialog themed activity width to screen width?

Tags: android

I am followin the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460418/best-way-to-show-a-edit-text-over-screen/460556#460556) to create an EditText input activity. But the view doesn't fill the width of the screen. How can I tell to fit the screen width?

[alt text http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/5057/activitythemed.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/5057/activitythemed.png)

```
<activity android:name="TextEntryActivity" 
          android:label="My Activity" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:text="@+id/txtValue"
        android:id="@+id/txtValue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <Button
        android:text="Done"
        android:id="@+id/btnDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I doubt if it's a duplicate. This question is about Dialog themed Activity which is not same as a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:minWidth` and/or `android:minHeight` in your LinearLayout.

Comment: To "fill_parent", in the same way as android:layout_width

Comment: That doesn't work out. error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'minWidth' with value 'fill_parent').

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be short with the answer.  You can use those properties to force a minimum size, i.e android:minWidth="200dip" android:minHeight="400dip".  You do have to specify the size absolutely, so "wrap_content" and "fill_parent" won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use AlertDialog instead Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't.  A dialog is only meant to wrap it's content.  If you want the content to fill the screen you should be using an activity