# Android: GridView width not wrapping to content?

Tags: android

I am trying to display a GridView in a Dialog.  Despite all my efforts, the GridView width grows to the entire screen, instead of wrapping to the columns.  The layout and an image depicting the issue are below (I set a background color for the GridView to illustrate the issue).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/colorgridview"
    android:background="#FF00CCBB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:stretchMode="none"
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Fixed layout_width does not work either. @ab11 - were you able to wrap the GridView? I'm trying to wrap it in a dialog. No luck so far.

Comment: Have you tried ExpandableGridview in this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this post is a bit outdated. But if someone needs a solution to this, this answer may come in handy.

It is possible to set the view's width after screen measurement.

To do this:

Let your class implement the OnGlobalLayoutListener. 
The screen is measured when the onGlobalLayout method is called. We can do our magic here.
GridView.getLayoutParams().width = ....

edit: 
I wasn't very clear on how to add the onGlobalLayoutListener. See plugmind's post, he shows how to add it.
[Can't figure out how to get view/layout width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581753/cant-figure-out-how-to-get-view-layout-width-height)

Kind regards,
Bram

Comment: I ended up not using a GridView because of this issue, so I did not test this solution.  But it sounds reasonable and you seem confident, so I will mark as answered so others can find this.  Thanks!

Comment: I did the same trick at my application, so I am confident that it works. Thanks for the accept :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`  instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` because wrap content use the minimum place it needs. On the other hand, fill_parent use all space needed. More over you should get rid of `"android:columnWidth="70dp".`

Comment: But, I want the columns to be of limited size and the dialog to wrap to that limited size.  I do not want it to fill the whole screen.

Comment: Oh my mistake sorry, i didn't understand that. Have you tried to build a custom Dialog with  android:layout_width="wrap_content" ? I'm not sure but it could be the Dialog size which fill the screen.

Comment: As noted in this link, I'm pretty sure Dialogs only "wrap_content": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961833/how-to-set-a-dialog-themed-activity-width-to-screen-width/2962168#2962168

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to set a fixed layout_width (in dp). Since the number of your columns is also fixed, could this be a workaround for you?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem...
I solved it with overridden onMeasure()

```
public class GridViewEx extends GridView {

    private int mRequestedNumColumns = 0;

    public GridViewEx(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GridViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GridViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        super.setNumColumns(numColumns);

        if (numColumns != mRequestedNumColumns) {
            mRequestedNumColumns = numColumns;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mRequestedNumColumns > 0) {
            int width = (mRequestedNumColumns * getColumnWidth())
                    + ((mRequestedNumColumns-1) * getHorizontalSpacing())
                    + getListPaddingLeft() + getListPaddingRight();

            setMeasuredDimension(width, getMeasuredHeight());    
        }
    }
}
```