# How to run Activity inside another Activity View?

Tags: android, android-activity, activitygroup

I'm need start activity inside a view, something like a fragment.
Unfortunately, I can't use fragments.

Where to start?

Comment: you can go with tabactivity...

Comment: "Unfortunately, I can't use fragments" - why cant you use fragments? What is something like a fragment but not?

Answer (score 7):

There are three options basically to achieve this:

- [Using Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
- [Using TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html)
- [Using another activity as a Dialog theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961833/how-to-set-a-dialog-themed-activity-width-to-screen-width)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try using dialog activity (choose activity theme as dialog)