# Blur or dim background when Android PopupWindow active

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

I would like to be able to either blur or dim the background when I show my popup window using `popup.showAtLocation`, and unblur/dim the background when `popup.dismiss` is called.

I have tried applying layout params `FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND` and `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` to my activity, but this appears to just blur and dim the background as soon my app is started.

How can I do blurring/dimming just with popups?

Comment: Word of warning: FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND is buggy on some phones and makes the phone very unresponsive (apparently the blur is done in software). On the Droid, for example. Other than that, what Macarse said - FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND needs to be applied to the window on the foreground.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to show a edit text over screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460418/best-way-to-show-a-edit-text-over-screen)

Comment: I am looking for the same answer to this question.  Is there some way I can programmatically dim the view that isw behind the popupwindow?

Comment: @Nick How you solved this problem..

Comment: **2021** perfect solution: https://github.com/sergei-lapin/BlurView

Answer (score 113):

The question was about the `Popupwindow` class, yet everybody has given answers that use the `Dialog` class. Thats pretty much useless if you need to use the `Popupwindow` class, because `Popupwindow` doesn't have a `getWindow()` method.

I've found a solution that actually works with `Popupwindow`. It only requires that the root of the xml file you use for the background activity is a `FrameLayout`. You can give the `Framelayout` element an `android:foreground` tag. What this tag does is specify a drawable resource that will be layered on top of the entire activity (that is, if the Framelayout is the root element in the xml file). You can then control the opacity (`setAlpha()`) of the foreground drawable.

You can use any drawable resource you like, but if you just want a dimming effect, create an xml file in the drawable folder with the `<shape>` tag as root.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

(See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape for more info on the `shape` element).
Note that I didn't specify an alpha value in the color tag that would make the drawable item transparent (e.g  `#ff000000`). The reason for this is that any hardcoded alpha value seems to override any new alpha values we set via the `setAlpha()` in our code, so we don't want that.
However, that means that the drawable item will initially be opaque (solid, non-transparent). So we need to make it transparent in the activity's `onCreate()` method.

Here's the Framelayout xml element code:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainmenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/shape_window_dim" >
...
... your activity's content
...
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the Activity's onCreate() method:

```
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate( savedInstanceState);

  setContentView( R.layout.activity_mainmenu);

  //
  // Your own Activity initialization code
  //

  layout_MainMenu = (FrameLayout) findViewById( R.id.mainmenu);
  layout_MainMenu.getForeground().setAlpha( 0);
}
```

Finally, the code to dim the activity:

```
layout_MainMenu.getForeground().setAlpha( 220); // dim

layout_MainMenu.getForeground().setAlpha( 0); // restore
```

The alpha values go from `0` (opaque) to `255` (invisible).
You should un-dim the activity when you dismiss the Popupwindow.

I haven't included code for showing and dismissing the Popupwindow, but here's a link to how it can be done: http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/

Comment: to ensure that this works on old devices, too you have to invalidate the foreground after every change made to its alpha-channel. I added this to the answer. +1 for the nice answer

Comment: I cant think of a reason which this isnt marked as the right answer.. awesome answer to say the least.

Comment: What about in view have Actionbar, You cant dim it

Comment: this worked best for me...the double popup answer below had a race condition so the dimmed popup sometimes was over the real popup

Comment: Almost perfect. The only drawback is you have to use FrameLayout since there's no "getForeground" method for other layouts.

Answer (score 91):

Since `PopupWindow` just adds a `View` to `WindowManager` you can use `updateViewLayout (View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)` to update the `LayoutParams` of your `PopupWindow`'s `contentView` after calling show..().

Setting the window flag `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` will dimm everything behind the window. Use `dimAmount` to control the amount of dim (1.0 for completely opaque to 0.0 for no dim).

Keep in mind that if you set a background to your `PopupWindow` it will put your `contentView` into a container, which means you need to update it's parent.

With background:

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(contentView, width, height);
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
popup.showAsDropDown(anchor);

View container = (View) popup.getContentView().getParent();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();
// add flag
p.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
p.dimAmount = 0.3f;
wm.updateViewLayout(container, p);
```

Without background:

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(contentView, width, height);
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
popup.showAsDropDown(anchor);

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) contentView.getLayoutParams();
// add flag
p.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
p.dimAmount = 0.3f;
wm.updateViewLayout(contentView, p);
```

Marshmallow Update:

On M PopupWindow wraps the contentView inside a FrameLayout called mDecorView. If you dig into the PopupWindow source you will find something like `createDecorView(View contentView)`.The main purpose of mDecorView is to handle event dispatch and content transitions, which are new to M. This means we need to add one more .getParent() to access the container.

With background that would require a change to something like:

```
View container = (View) popup.getContentView().getParent().getParent();
```

---

**Better alternative for API 18+**

A less hacky solution using `ViewGroupOverlay`:

1) Get a hold of the desired root layout

```
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

2) Call `applyDim(root, 0.5f);` or `clearDim()`

```
public static void applyDim(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, float dimAmount){
    Drawable dim = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);
    dim.setBounds(0, 0, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight());
    dim.setAlpha((int) (255 * dimAmount));

    ViewGroupOverlay overlay = parent.getOverlay();
    overlay.add(dim);
}

public static void clearDim(@NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewGroupOverlay overlay = parent.getOverlay();
    overlay.clear();
}
```

Comment: This no longer seems to work on devices running Android 6.0 Marshmallow. The layoutParams don't cast to `WindowManager.LayoutParams`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Thank's for pointing it out. I haven't tested it on M yet. Will update ASAP.

Comment: @ http://stackoverflow.com/users/308153/robert I also had same issue. I used above code with background.

Comment: If p is null use this: `if (p != null)
 {
 //same
 }
 else
 {
 popupView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener()
 {
 public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
 {
 v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
 WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
 p.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
 p.dimAmount = 0.3f;
 wm.updateViewLayout(v, p);
 }
 });
 }`

Comment: FYI When I use this on lower API levels (e.g. 15 and 20) it crashes because  popup.getContentView().getParent() does not return View so casting it will cause a crash. For this case I used @BeytanKurt's method as the fallback.

Comment: @MarkusRubey what i have need to change for the android M , it's crashin of this line () popup.getContentView().getParent().getParent();

Answer (score 30):

In your xml file add something like this with width and height as 'match_parent'.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bac_dim_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#C0000000"
        android:visibility="gone" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity oncreate

```
//setting background dim when showing popup
back_dim_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.share_bac_dim_layout);
```

Finally make visible when you show your popupwindow and make its visible gone when you exit popupwindow.

```
back_dim_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
back_dim_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: but this won't dim the action/tool bar.

Comment: Plz tell me how to action toolbar dim

Comment: add back_dim_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 in PopupWindow.OnDismissListener

Answer (score 12):

Another trick is to use 2 popup windows instead of one. The 1st popup window will simply be a dummy view with translucent background which provides the dim effect. The 2nd popup window is your intended popup window.

**Sequence while creating pop up windows:**
Show the dummy pop up window 1st and then the intended popup window.

**Sequence while destroying:**
Dismiss the intended pop up window and then the dummy pop up window.

*The best way to link these two is to add an [OnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.OnDismissListener.html) and override the `onDismiss()` method of the intended to dimiss the dummy popup window from their.*

Code for the dummy popup window:

fadepopup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/fadePopup"
    android:background="#AA000000">
</LinearLayout>
```

Show fade popup to dim the background

```
private PopupWindow dimBackground() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) EPGGRIDActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fadepopup,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.fadePopup));
    PopupWindow fadePopup = new PopupWindow(layout, windowWidth, windowHeight, false);
    fadePopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
    return fadePopup;
}
```

Comment: Almost works for me...sometimes, there's a race condition where the popupwindow is behind the dim/dummy popup window.  Haven't found a workaround yet...even delaying the showing of the popupwindow to give it time behind the delayed one doesn't help :-P

Comment: @kenyee I've found a fix for this issue. I show 'fade' popup first, and then in order to show second popup I am using myFadePopup.getContentView().post( ... myPopup.showAtLocation ... );

Answer (score 5):

I've found a solution for this

Create a custom transparent dialog and inside that dialog open the popup window:

```
dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
emptyDialog = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.empty, null);

/* blur background*/
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=0.0f;  
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND); 
dialog.setContentView(emptyDialog);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogIx)
    {
        mQuickAction.show(emptyDialog); //open the PopupWindow here
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

xml for the dialog(R.layout.empty):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     style="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

now you want to dismiss the dialog when Popup window dismisses. so

```
mQuickAction.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDismiss()
    {
        if(dialog!=null)
        {
            dialog.dismiss(); // dismiss the empty dialog when the PopupWindow closes
            dialog = null;
        }
    }
});
```

Note: I've used [`NewQuickAction`](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction) plugin for creating PopupWindow here. It can also be done on native Popup Windows

Answer (score 1):

For me, something like Abdelhak Mouaamou's answer works, tested on API level 16 and 27.

Instead of using `popupWindow.getContentView().getParent()` and casting the result to `View` (which crashes on API level 16 cause there it returns a `ViewRootImpl` object which isn't an instance of `View`) I just use `.getRootView()` which returns a view already, so no casting required there.

Hope it helps someone :)

complete working example scrambled together from other stackoverflow posts, just copy-paste it, e.g., in the onClick listener of a button:

```
// inflate the layout of the popup window
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
if(inflater == null) {
    return;
}
//View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_popup_layout, null); // this version gives a warning cause it doesn't like null as argument for the viewRoot, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832497 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404951
View popupView = View.inflate(MyParentActivity.this, R.layout.my_popup_layout, null);

// create the popup window
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        true // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
        );

// do something with the stuff in your popup layout, e.g.:
//((TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.textview_popup_helloworld))
//      .setText("hello stackoverflow");

// dismiss the popup window when touched
popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
});

// show the popup window
// which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window token
popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
//popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false); // doesn't seem to change anything for me

View container = popupWindow.getContentView().getRootView();
if(container != null) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams)container.getLayoutParams();
    p.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    p.dimAmount = 0.3f;
    if(wm != null) {
        wm.updateViewLayout(container, p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this repo will help for you:[BasePopup](https://github.com/razerdp/BasePopup)

This is my repo, which is used to solve various problems of PopupWindow.

In the case of using the library, if you need to blur the background, just call `setBlurBackgroundEnable(true).`

See the wiki for more details.（Language in zh-cn）

[BasePopup:wiki](http://%20https://github.com/razerdp/BasePopup/wiki/API#setblurbackgroundenableboolean-blurbackgroundenable)

Answer (score 1):

```
findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout).setAlpha((float) 0.7);
```

`R.id.drawer_layout` is the id of the layout of which you want to dim the brightness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to do that.
Create an activity and in your `AndroidManifest.xml` define the activity as:

```
    <activity android:name=".activities.YourActivity"
              android:label="@string/your_activity_label"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick. I applied to this to my only activity, which is in the background when I show a popup window which is just an inflated layout I have, and not a separate activity.

How do I apply FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND to a PopupWindow?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i follow [uhmdown's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10725022/9256916) answer for dimming background activity when pop window is open. But it creates problem for me. it was dimming activity and include popup window (means dimmed-black layered on both activity and popup also, it can not be separate them).

so i tried this way,

create an *dimming_black.xml* file for dimming effect,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#33000000" />
</shape>
```

And add as `background` in `FrameLayout` as root xml tag, also put my other controls in `LinearLayout` like this `layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ff_drawable_black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white">

        // other codes...
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

at last i show popup on my `MainActivity` with some extra parameter set as below.

```
           //instantiate popup window
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(viewPopup, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);

            //display the popup window
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout_ff, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

**Result:**
[image]

it works for me, also solved problem as commented by *BaDo*. With this `Actionbar` also can be dimmed.

P.s i am not saying *uhmdown's* is wrong. i learnt form his answer and try to evolve for my problem. I also confused whether this is a good way or not.

Any suggestions is also appreciated also sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Since You are trying to pop up your dialog window by blurring the background screen, You must use this set of lines. You need to fetch the dialog attributes first, then set up some alpha values for the dialog attributes.

Now, your dialog with blur background is ready. But the important factor is to set a Flag `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` for the window.

Now the result is yours. Hope it will helpful for someone...

```
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.dimAmount=0.6f;
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a popup that takes up the entire size of the parent:

```java
int width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
int height = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
```

Then, in the xml layout of the popup, I set the background translucent and created a child layout that matches the constraints of its children and has a solid background. This dims everything behind the contents of the child `ConstraintLayout`.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#60000000">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<!-- Child Components Here -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code work

```
        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        pwindo.setOutsideTouchable(false);

        View container = (View) pwindo.getContentView().getParent();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();
        p.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        p.dimAmount = 0.3f;
        wm.updateViewLayout(container, p);
```