# Blurring screen under Activity results in black screen

Tags: android

When I use

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

in my `Activity` I don't get slightly blurred screen under current `Activity` but completely black one (top `Activity` is fine). Need to say it is also black in sample which came with SDK. Can somebody suggest how to make it blurry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml add this line to your Activity declaration: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` otherwise the activity will have a solid background (and thus blur has no effect).

Also, this post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active) is helpful, in particular the cautionary notes. On older devices this causes your application to become unresponsive (it is a CPU-intense software rendering), and on newer devices this constant is deprecated and no longer has any effect (see Android Documentation for [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND)).

Deprecated on latest versions of OS (check documentation).

Comment: I have this theme specified in AndroidManifest.xml, sorry not mentioned that.

Comment: What version of Android are you running? I'm not positive, but I believe that constant was deprecated in Honeycomb API 11. I can confirm on 4.0 ICS or 4.1 Jelly Bean this constant doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Note: the flag FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND is depreciated. 
You can use FLAG_DIM_BEHIND Instead.