# How to blur or dim background when pop show in android

Tags: android

I want to blur or dim the background of activity when pop up show to user and please its
a pop up not dialog so please tell me the solution for pop up not dialog. i use below 
code to show pop up

```
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layoutInflate, width, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        // popupWindow.showAsDropDown(layoutInflate);
        //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(layoutInflate, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Comment: WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND This flag has been deprecated now. Maybe that's the reason why you don't seem to get what you want. But even I am looking for a way to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active

check this link