# How to blur or Fade screen when pop up show in activtity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blur or dim background when Android PopupWindow active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active)

I want to blur or fade the screen when my custom pop up show in my activity.
I have made custom popup by using popup window class. but when pop up show 
then my activity layout not blur or dim or fade so please help me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layoutInflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout, relativeLayout);     
PopupWindow tagPopupWindow tagPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(layoutInflate, width, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems a duplicate to [Blur or dim background when Android PopupWindow active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active).

I also recommend that you use Dialog instead.