# How to dim the background for a PopupWindow?

Tags: listview, android, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment (v4) and onClick of any row of the ListView I show a popup (using PopupWindow) which displays related information for that row...

Now I want to dim / blur the background when the popup is showing. Since the view is too complex I can't use DialogFragment. So Please don't suggest options related to that.

I have read [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active) but can't understand how to use that for a ListFragment

How can I achieve that bluring effect ?

please help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blur or dim background when Android PopupWindow active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active)

Answer (score 0):

This is for any one facing a similar problem. I replaced Popupwinows with Dialogs and the issue is solved automatically. I created a super class MyDialog which extends Dialog and used my custom theme in its constructor and all my other Dialogs extended this class .

However I am still not convinced that their is  no way to achieve that for popup windows. The question is still open for an answer related to popup windows..