# making user friendly help and hint for app android programming

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm sorry for my bad english speaking. i am developing an android app. iwant make a user friendly help for my layouts if you see "viber" or "go backup" thease apps show a alpha layout on main layout for user helping on first run. for example see theas picture
1- main layout

[image]

2- when help is showing

[image]

how can i make something like this? any idea? thank u

Comment: there's not any idea please?

Comment: You question isn't the most clear, I am not clear on what a 'viber' is

Comment: i want to make a help for my app. when app ran first time a alpha layout showed on app's main layout, just like above pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few of my ideas of how you might do this

- Create a popup with no background color attribute, and dim the background, then using an image view, placed overtop of the icon that you are helping the user with, show a highlighted picture of your icon

Making a popup - [How to create a popup window in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498605/how-to-create-a-popup-window-in-android)

Diming the background - [Blur or dim background when Android PopupWindow active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active)

- Or you could create a sperate layout, by copying your original layout, putting it in a framelayout, and overlaying a dim empty image view, and putting your text view, your button, and a small highlighted icon overtop of this view

Framelayout -  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Hope this helps, if you have any questions feel free to ask