# Dim or Blur background in activity

Tags: android

In one of my project I used `PopupWindow`. My problem is while viewing popupwindow the design seems to be uncomfortable to work. So I want to dim or blur my activity background. I searched a lot, but most of the answers seems only for `Dialog` not for `PopupWindow`. Is it possible in android to dim our activity background while viewing `PopupWindaow`.

Comment: why not use a Dialog if it provides dimming the background?

Comment: No friend. I have completed my project. If it is not possible means then only way to move `Dialog`. Now only I am searching friend.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting the background to the layout of the pop-up window with the following.

```
android:background="#80FFFFFF"
```

Thnaks..And it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use this :

```
ColorDrawable dw = new ColorDrawable(0xb0000000);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(dw);
```

Comment: I wasn't clear on what 'this' is.. but it got me on the right track -thanks!  For a dialog popup, this worked: dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(dw);

Answer (score 1):

There is always a work around. Before showing your `PopupWindow` use another `PopupWindow` which has nothing but a dark translucent tint. Also when dismissing dismiss both pop up windows in the reverse sequence.

For code see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active/15631963#15631963)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible, try `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"` , it will make your activity transparent.

Comment: while viewing my `PopupWindaow` only I want it to dim friend. After closing `PopupWindaow`I want to cancel that dim.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 Window window = popUpView.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    wlp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    wlp.dimAmount = (float) 1.0;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

Comment: PopupWindow does not have a `getWindow()` method.