# Creating a Dialog with dimmed background

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I've created a Dialog that appears when a button is clicked. I made a custom layout for it and coded it like this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog (CheckpointsActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_continue);
//rest of the code...
```

This is how the Dialog looks now:
[image]

And this is how I want it to look like:

[image]

It should be a lot darker in the background with a gradient effect. I can't seem to find any info on how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own theme by inheriting android.R.style.Theme_Translucent and changing the values as appropriate for the design you are looking for and using that theme instead of the provided theme?

Comment: One way to achieve this is to use a FrameLayout and add a PopupWindow to it. 

It is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10725022/1235555)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a dialog box with the same background and gradient and then make the ui on top of that.