# Darken Background after Popup window opened android

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to dark the background after popup window open and restore everything like before after dismissing. I have searched google and seen some tutorial also. But I don't be able to understand how it is possible. Here's My Java Code:

```
public void displayPopupWindow() {
    View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup,null);
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(this);
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popup.setFocusable(true);
    popup.setWidth(400);
    popup.setHeight(580);
    popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    Button button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View layout) {
            popup.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

Here my popup xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:id="@+id/popup"
>
Various views and button
</RelativeLayout>
```

What should I do now?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: i have already tried this. But it is not worked for me

Answer (score -1):

you can try this out

replace

```
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

with this in your code

```
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
```

you can change any background as per choice.

Comment: is the black color defined like this in your color.java file please check

Comment: @ColorInt public static final int BLACK  = 0xFF000000;

Comment: if not then you can do this it will work i have tested.

Comment: also there is one more alternative opening the layout using alert dialog box i have the code as well

Comment: Use android:background="@null"

Comment: ok i have a code in which i have opened pop up using alert dialog box with a custom layout.In that i have tried to make background black and was successful. so if you want to open pop up using alert dialog box then i can share that code. but in that case your current code will be of no use as you are using "PopupWindow" class.

Comment: But your layout that you have created will get used in that.

Comment: please share brother! Thanks in Advance @Apoorv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131267/discussion-between-bill-redoy-and-apoorv-mehrotra).