# When Popup window is active, make screen into dimmer expect selected view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv, android-popupwindow, leanback

When the popupwindow is active, I want to make the screen into dimmer or blur expect selected view. Same like below mentioned image.
[image]

I have tried the below code but its dimming entire screen

```
public static void dimBehind(PopupWindow popupWindow) {
       View container = popupWindow.getContentView().getRootView();
       Context context = popupWindow.getContentView().getContext();
       WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
       WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();
       p.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
       p.screenBrightness=
       p.dimAmount = 0.3f;
       wm.updateViewLayout(container, p);
   }
```

below code is for popup window

```
public void showpopupwindow(View view){
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,null);



       //instantiate popup window
       PopupWindow  popupWindow = new PopupWindow(mContext);
       popupWindow.setContentView(customView);
       popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

       //display the popup window
       popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view);
       dimBehind(popupWindow);


       TextView textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4;
       textView1=customView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
       textView2=customView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
       textView3=customView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);
       textView4=customView.findViewById(R.id.textview4);

   }
```

Please help me.....

Comment: Hae you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active)?

Comment: Using that code its dimming entire screen, But I want to like the attached image.

Comment: I assume that you are going to make your image as a background image with a dim effect am I correct?

Comment: NO, when I do a long press it will open the popup window, except selected view and popup window remaining all views should blur or dim. the above mentioned code is dimming entire screen with my selected view also.