# Activity dialog show with blurry view

Tags: java, android

I want to open `Activity` as a Dialog. I tried the codes below :

Added this style in **`style.xml`**

```
<style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

And In Manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.AddVideoView"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
    android:theme="@style/NoTitleDialog"/>
```

**`XML`**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_140sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Dialog showed perfectly but it's blurry. So how do I show the dialog perfectly without the overlay?

See below image for better understanding :

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you post xml for the activity

Comment: I add xml file @Sajith

Comment: can you post code where you show the dialog.

Comment: Probably duplicate check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active)

Comment: I already check this link @MehulSolanki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this line to your code:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

or you can preventing from dim effect like this:

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```