# Is there an open-source audio-playing Android app that accepts intents?

Tags: android, open-source, audio

The Music app on my 2.1 phone [accepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114471/android-launching-music-player-using-intent) the ACTION_VIEW intent, but it's not very friendly to use from other applications.

I'd like it to:

- Accept a song, descriptive text, and start time (so it can start in the middle of a song/podcast)
- Immediately begin playing the song
- Provide a user interface like the [Android Music app](http://www.simplehelp.net/images/android_music_windows/android_music_windows17.png)
- [Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449484/android-capturing-the-return-of-an-activity) which button was pressed (if applicable) and the current song position
- Return when the song ends
- Show [in front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget) of the lock screen.
- Hitting back from the app should bring me back to my application (maybe I have to use the app as a library for this?).
- Add itself to the status bar while the song is playing
- Continue to play the song when the app is not in the foreground

Is there anything like this, or do I need to build my own?

Comment: Off the cuff, I think you have an impossible set of requirements.

Comment: Do you mean it's impossible to implement? Which parts?

Comment: Bullets 4, 5, 6, 7, and 9 seem difficult to impossible to all implement at the same time. Bullet 6, in particular, is pretty evil IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented all but the last three bullets in [LibListenScreen](https://github.com/pydave/LibListenScreen). I have to learn about status bars and services before I can finish the rest of it.