# how to develop a replacement for the android lock screen

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

I need to put my app on the lock screen (android 2.2)!

I think there are two options for do this:

1. Develop an app to replace android's lock screen. This app whould be called when the off button is pressed.
2. Insert my app button into android's actual lockscreen, so, my app would work, even if the screen is locked, and eventually, my app could unlock the screen.

I don't know how to do it, but I do know it is possible, since some music players can be downloaded and the music player options are in the lockscreen.

Can anybody help me out?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(1) is totally feasible and there are many lockscreen alternatives apps available.

(2) will depend on what lockscreen are you talking about and what is what your app does. Firmware lockscreens do not allow usually widgets in them. At most, they have a method to interact with the call/sms log and the music player, but that's it.

So, unless your app does one of those two, your only option is pretty much (1).

Comment: I understand ... I want my app take a picture and save it in the sd card. So, how can I do it? does anybody knows any code, example or anything to help me do one of the 2 things I listed before?

Comment: Search "android camera" here in SO and you will find several examples, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449484/android-capturing-the-return-of-an-activity/449824#449824 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent