# setting the time on button in different activity in android

Tags: android

I'm new to the android .In my application  i have two activities. In the first activity  i have a button and in second activity  i have two buttons .When i click the button it's going to second activity. In second activity one button for time picker  and another  button for setting the time .my problem is time picker set the time that time display on the button in first activity.when i click the set  button it's going to the first activity  but time not displaying on the button in first activity .

Comment: Post your code. Sounds like your just not passing back the time correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android: Capturing the return of an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449484/android-capturing-the-return-of-an-activity)