# return text from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity

i want to start activityB from activityA and return string from activityB then resume activityA is it possible?
i refer [Android: Capturing the return of an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449484/android-capturing-the-return-of-an-activity)

Comment: Perfect. And what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use startActivityForResult() method if you need to pass data back from an  activity. 
E.x: return data from Activity B

Activity A:

Step1:Call StartActivityForResult() method

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
// use startActivityForResult(Intent,request_code)  method()
//with request_code is used to identify.
starActivityForResult(i,1)
```

Step2:
   You must implements onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) method

```
//check requestCode and resultCode    
if(requestCode==1)
{

  if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)

  {
    //get Data
    String temp =  data.getData().toString();
   }  


}
```

Activity B:

```
 //set Data return Activity B at anywhere you want
 Intent data = new Intent()
 data.setData("String_Test");

 setResult(RESULT_OK,data)
 //close the activity
 finish();
```

Note: instead of using setData method(), you also able to use putExtras(Bunble object) to send data.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to Work on `onActivityResult()`.
Here are some Tutorials.

[One](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/return-result-to-onactivityresult.html),
[Two](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html)

In example One you will find your Answer. Hope this is Enough.