# Android - Getting activity object from startActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to get the instance of the `Activity` that was created when `startActivity()` is called. However, `startActivity()` returns a void value.

I guess `startActivity()` doesn't wait until the `Activity` is created.

Is there a different way for me to get hold of the `activity` that was just created on the call to `startActivity`? Or, perhaps I can create an `Activity` instance myself and register it somewhere so that `startActivity` can find it.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449484/android-capturing-the-return-of-an-activity

Comment: Note that your first activity will be paused when you start the second.

Comment: Maybe if you explain why you need this, there might be other ways to solve your problem. Plus, as said above, your first activity will be in a paused/stopped state (code usually shouldn't be running in these states)

Comment: This sounds like a dirty hack to circumvent the normal operation of the Android system architecture.   Your question give strong hints that the architecture of your application is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Activity you're trying to look at in your own app, or in another app?

If they're both your Activities, then it might be OK to do what you're trying to do, although Activities ought to remain separated. You might consider using Fragments instead, since they can "communicate" with each other through their parent Activity.

If they're not both in your app, then you can't get the other Activity instance, because by definition it's in another process. Moreover, the Android system prevents it, because it would be a big security hole.

In general, I squint a bit at attempts to get an *instance* of something outside of your own component, unless it's an instance of something in the system. Communication between components should be by Intent, bound Service features, or content URIs. Passing around instances leaves you open to memory leaks.